# Cumulative translation on Matrix3x2F

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, direct2d

I am working on a WinRT app that uses D2D to display a bitmap.  I am looking to incorporate multitouch to be able to pan and zoom in the bitmap.

I am using the OnManipulatedUpdated event to update a cumulative transform.  I have found a way to find a cumulative scale factor, but can't seem to find a cumulative translation factor (I don't want the user to pan outside of the size of the scaled image.

Is there a way to find out what the cumulative translation is?

Here is my code:

```
D2D1::Matrix3x2F m_mxTransform;

property float CurrentScaleFactor
    {
        float get() { return sqrt(fabs(m_mxTransform.Determinant())); }
    }

void OnManipulationUpdated(
_In_ Windows::UI::Input::GestureRecognizer^ recognizer,
_In_ Windows::UI::Input::ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs^ args)
{
Point position = args->Position;
Point positionDelta = args->Delta.Translation;

float currentScale = CurrentScaleFactor;
float preAdjustedScale = args->Delta.Scale;
ManipulationDelta adjustedDelta = LimitManipulationScale(args->Delta, currentScale);
float newScale = currentScale * adjustedDelta.Scale;

//Update the transformation to 
D2D1::Matrix3x2F transformDelta;
if (preAdjustedScale == adjustedDelta.Scale)
{
    transformDelta = 
        D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(adjustedDelta.Scale, adjustedDelta.Scale, D2D1::Point2F(args->Position.X, args->Position.Y)) *
        D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(args->Delta.Translation.X, args->Delta.Translation.Y);
}
else  // don't translate
{
    transformDelta = 
        D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(adjustedDelta.Scale, adjustedDelta.Scale, D2D1::Point2F(args->Position.X, args->Position.Y));
}
m_mxTransform = m_mxTransform * transformDelta;

....
m_d2dContext->SetTransform(m_mxTransform);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it...

```
    /* x-coordinate that we are currently translated by */
    property float CurrentTranslationX
    {
        float get() { return m_mxTransform._31; }
    }

    /* y-coordinate that we are currently translated by */
    property float CurrentTranslationY
    {
        float get() { return m_mxTransform._32; }
    }
```